# Issue on putting cursor into dynamically added input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on my demo code, why am I not able to move cursor into the dynamically added input? As you can see I am using `.focus()` to enable user to start entering text in without any need of clicking there but it is not working

```js
$(".container").dblclick(function(e) {
  $(this).append($('<input type="text"/>').css({ //some CSS here
  }).focus());
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative
}

input {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could focus on the last input element:

```
$(".container").dblclick(function(e) {
    $(this).append($('<input type="text"/>').css({ //some CSS here
    }));
    $("input:last").focus();
});
```

```js
$(".container").dblclick(function(e) {
  $(this).append($('<input type="text"/>').css({ //some CSS here
  }));
  $("input:last").focus();
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative
}

input {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `focus` before appending the input to DOM.

Try the following:

```js
$(".container").dblclick(function(e) {
  $('<input type="text"/>')
    .css({ /* some CSS here */ })
    .appendTo(this)
    .focus();
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative
}

input {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```